# angular-cli with cordova plugins error

Tags: angular, cordova

When i build an Angular 4 app with ng-build I get the following error when I try to access device.uuid:

> /navigation.component.ts (14,5): Cannot find name  'device'.

All plugins I refer to within TS files cause this error. I don't know how to use Cordova and the Cordova plugins correctly with Angular-CLI. I have written the cordova.js and the script files for the plugins into the scripts part of angular-cli.json without success. I only find examples with ionic everywhere.

The problem is that the Cordova script and the scripts for the plugins are actually only available at runtime of the app and not while the compile time. That's why the angular cli doesn't really know the scripts. And even though I entered these scripts in the script part,  device is not found at device.uuid. I have also included all index.d.ts files via @types/..... Visual Studio Code jumps to the correct declaration file.

Comment: Add `declare var device;` below your imports in the `.ts` files where you want to use the device plugin. This lets typescript know that you are sure that the `device` variable will exist later.

Comment: I have included the declaration files. There are var device; already definded. Visual studio knows the variable Device. But when i call ng build there was the error

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to include cordova plugin in your angular-cli.

First of all make sure you have called the cordova.js in your index.html. `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`.

After that if you want a build for android you need to specify the base path also in index.html `<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" />`

Then install a cordova plugin in your cordova app and declare it in your angular ts, ex: `declare var device:any;` and if you want to call the device you need to use  the the cordova `deviceready` event listener:

```
declare var device:any;
export class ExampleClass {
    constructor(){
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(device.cordova);
    }
}
```

This can be used only if you run the app on mobile device.

Comment: OK. When i write 

`declare var device:any;` top of the class, it works. But i dont understnad why. I have installed "@types/cordova-plugin-device". This is the declaration file from the cordova device plugin. In this declaration file (index.d.ts) there are already the code 

`declare var device: Device;` 

The index.d.ts file was in the folder "node_modules\@types\cordova-plugin-device". In the tsconfig.json file there was the following entry: 

`"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
  ]`

But does the angular cli also know about the rootTypes?

Comment: I never tried to set typeings. But If you declare your variable in these  way  below your imports in your ts file you are saying for typescript that you are sure that the device variable will exist later.

Comment: Yeah. But I don't want the type any. There is an interface Device.

`interface Device {
    uuid: string;
 ...
}`

declare var device: Device;`


[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cordova-plugin-device) -> [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/cordova-plugin-device)

Here is the declaration of the variable device. But with the desired interface Device and not with any. In the tsconfig.json file, i set  
`"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]`
Where can I tell the angular-cli to use the index. d. ts files in the folder?